# Excel VBA Max 10 Values from dictionary

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get the 10 maximum values from a dictionary. Given i have some data in the following form:

```
ID Value
1  23
2  342
5  -23
...
```

What is the fastest way to do this?

To make things clearer the following is a code-listing of how i would do this in C#:

```
class Custom {
  int ID {get; set;}
  double Val {get; set;}
  double Val2 {get; set;}
}

List<Custom> GetMaxValues(List<Custom> myList){
  return myList.SortByDescending(c => c.Val).Take(10);
}
```

I have included a second value in the C# custom class, since i would actually need several values in the dictionary. Would a multidimensional array be a good solution to hold triplets of data. Then i could simply run some sorting algorithm and pick the last 10 items from the array.

Edit: I just noticed that i can't use an array since the data has different types. The ID's are actually string and not integers.

Comment: why is this labeled VBA for c# code ???

Comment: What's your existing code? Dictionaries are not guaranteed to be ordered. As to the array, you could use a multi-dimensional array of variants, that would allow different types

Comment: @iDevlop That threw me at first to, but the C# code is to illustrate what they want to do in VBA, sort of a "how would I translate this C# to VBA" question.

Comment: Might be easiest to read the data into 3 columns of a spreadsheet and use Excel's built in sort, which can handle multiple columns. A common trick is to create a temporary worksheet just for this purpose and then delete it, so you don't have to worry about overwriting any data.

Comment: You could solved the mixed type problem by using a jagged array. First dimension for ID and second dimension for holding arrays of the two values.

Comment: John's idea of using a temp sheet is probably the easiest way of doing this. VBA's support for data structures is rubbish.

Comment: Regarding the C# code: It is indeed just for illustration. To show how things would be handled in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've generated some VBA that should return the top *N* values from a dictionary into an array. I've tried breaking it down into helper functions to make it a bit more legible and to divide the duties for reusability. Certainly, it can be developed further for error checking, but I mocked it up relatively quickly (for example, it ignores duplicates).

Let us know if it does what you need it to do, and if you need any help with adoption into your own code.

```
Sub PerformTheActions()
    Dim oDictionary As Object

    Set oDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    AddToDictionary oDictionary, Sheet1.Range("A1:A33")

    va = ReturnTopNValuesFromDict(oDictionary, 10)

    For i = LBound(va) To UBound(va)
        MsgBox "Key: " & va(i, 1) & " Value: " & va(i, 2)
    Next i

End Sub

' Below is just a helper function to add a bunch of numbers into a dictionary
' You won't need to use it because you likely have other business logic to create your dict
Private Sub AddToDictionary(odict As Object, rng As Range)
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim nID As Integer

    nID = 1
    For Each cel In rng
        If Not odict.exists(cel.Value) Then
            odict.Add nID, cel.Value
            nID = nID + 1
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub

Private Function ReturnTopNValuesFromDict(odict As Object, nTop As Integer) As Variant()
    Dim topN() As Variant
    Dim nCounter As Integer
    Dim vCutoff As Variant
    Dim nCutoffIndex As Long

    ReDim topN(1 To nTop, 1 To 2)
    nCounter = 1

    For Each oitem In odict
        If nCounter <= nTop Then
            topN(nCounter, 1) = oitem
            topN(nCounter, 2) = odict(oitem)
            nCounter = nCounter + 1
        Else
            vCutoff = topN(LBound(topN), 2)
            nCutoffIndex = LBound(topN)

            For i = LBound(topN) + 1 To UBound(topN)
                If topN(i, 2) < vCutoff Then
                    vCutoff = topN(i, 2)
                    nCutoffIndex = i
                End If
            Next i

            If vCutoff > odict(oitem) Then
                'Do nothing because lowest value in array is greater than this item
            Else
                topN(nCutoffIndex, 1) = oitem
                topN(nCutoffIndex, 2) = odict(oitem)
            End If
        End If
    Next oitem
    BubbleSortArray topN
    ReturnTopNValuesFromDict = topN
End Function

Private Function BubbleSortArray(vArray As Variant) As Variant()
    Dim vPlaceHolder As Variant
    Dim nFirst As Long
    Dim nSecond As Long


    For nFirst = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
        For nSecond = nFirst + 1 To UBound(vArray)
            If vArray(nFirst, 2) < vArray(nSecond, 2) Then
                vPlaceHolder = vArray(nFirst, 1)
                vArray(nFirst, 1) = vArray(nSecond, 1)
                vArray(nSecond, 1) = vPlaceHolder

                vPlaceHolder = vArray(nFirst, 2)
                vArray(nFirst, 2) = vArray(nSecond, 2)
                vArray(nSecond, 2) = vPlaceHolder
            End If
        Next nSecond
    Next nFirst
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a dictionary - use an ArrayList instead:

```
Sub foo()

Dim myList As Object
Dim resultArray As Variant

'// create the arraylist and populate it
Set myList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For i = 100 To 1 Step -1
    myList.Add i
Next

'// sort the values numerically
myList.Sort

'// remove the last 90 elements (we're only interested in the first 10)
myList.RemoveRange 10, myList.Count - 10

'// pass the values to a single dimension array
resultArray = myList.ToArray()

'// print the results
Debug.Print Join$(resultArray, ",")

End Sub
```

[MSDN ArrayList Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I like it. Another good idea if dictionaries aren't required.